# Composer.json in a simple PHP

Tags: php, composer-php

I knew this is so basic question but I completely have no idea how to deal with this. I have a single PHP page that contain a form and simple PHP code to insert form data to database.

Now I want to test a Composer based code 
[Code Link](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php)

I just simply copy this entire code and try to run but it shows syntax error. Yes I already installed `composer.json`

`charge-credit-card.php` is the file that I just created as mention on github 
[image]

My problem is not this code I want to learn how I run any Composer based code without any framework. Just simple way to test any code.

Comment: you need to include composer autoload.php file. It will autoload classes as necesary.

Comment: I think it's no good idea to handle with credit card charges if you "completely have no idea how to deal with this" as you say.

Comment: i am just test code not actually deal with credit card

Comment: aside from using `composer.json` (i.e. creating it where you see fit, adding deps, etc.) - did you actually run `composer install` to pull the deps into `vendor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to learn how to use Composer have a look at tutorials like this:
https://www.dev-metal.com/composer-tutorial/

The key is to require Composer's `autoload.php` in your own main project file (e.g. in your `index.php`).

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

This loads the Composer autoloader. So this line includes everything that Composer has downloaded into the project.

Comment: will you please confirm if i want to include any composer based code . just i have to `require` `autoload.php` file and after that code simple add in my page .. no need any extra command

Comment: Yes this requires every package you downloaded with Composer as I already wrote. Anyway you still have to write your own app to use this code. I really recommend to read some tutorials. This is nothing you will learn here in 2 minutes by asking a question. And I recommend to start with something more simple than credit card charging.